# XML - Validate attributes with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following (fixed) XML structure:

```
<root>
  <metadata>
    <field name="ID" origin="email" value="1234" />
    <field name="Message" origin="email" value="Hello World" />
    <field name="Timestamp" origin="channel" value="1231223123" />
  </metadata>
</root>
```

I now want to create a XSD file to validate.
I have to validate that each field with combinition name/origin is unique and exactly with these values of the attributes.

I am able to create a XSD for validation that a field must contain these attributes, but not the above task.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use XSD 1.1 assertions for this.